# Boto: Find if bucket is public or private

Tags: boto3

I don't find a way to easily know if my AWS S3 buckets are public or private.

I was expecting to do `list_bucket_response = s3client.list_buckets()` and directly know if the bucket is publicly accessible or not.
I've came across https://jgreenemi.com/how-to-check-if-your-s3-buckets-allow-public-read-acls/ but in my case when I list buckets I don't get an URI.

I also tried `s3client.get_bucket_acl(Bucket=bucket_name)` without success.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to evaluate 3 different conditions to check whether a bucket is public or not:

- Policies
- ACLs
- Block public access setting

According to this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html#access-control-block-public-access-policy-status):

1. Use **get_public_access_block()** method to check if block public access option is set.

```
response = s3client.get_public_access_block(Bucket='bucket_name')
```

If both of the following are set to true, then the bucket is not public:

```
response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicAcls']
response['PublicAccessBlockConfiguration']['BlockPublicPolicy']
```

2. Use **get_bucket_policy_status**() method to check if policies allow public access.

> **get_bucket_policy_status**
>
> Retrieves the policy status for an Amazon S3 bucket, indicating whether the bucket is public

```
response = s3_client.get_bucket_policy_status(Bucket='bucket_name')
```

The bucket is public if the following is true:

```
response['PolicyStatus']['IsPublic']
```

3. Check ACLs to see if grantee is AllUsers or AuthenticatedUsers groups.

```
response = s3client.get_bucket_acl(Bucket='bucket_name')
```

The bucket is public if the ACL grants any permissions to members of the predefined AllUsers or AuthenticatedUsers groups.

Grantee (response['Grants'][*]['Grantee']):

- Type: Group
- URI:

  - http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AuthenticatedUsers
  - http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers

You can further evaluate object ACLs if required.

Answer (score 1):

Actually get_bucket_policy_status will throw an exception if you turned off public access
I found this piece of code works well

```
    try:
        access = s3.get_public_access_block(Bucket=bucket['Name'])
        print (access)
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchPublicAccessBlockConfiguration':
            print('\t no Public Access')
        else:
            print("unexpected error: %s" % (e.response))
```

Comment: If a NoSuchPublicAccessBlockConfiguration exception is raised that just means it's not configured and so technically that's not true - though this answer is from 2020 and so perhaps it was different back then.